# Pulling multiple rows from the same table from a JOIN table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a join table for a schedule (weeks 1, 2, 3, etc) that connects users. Each week in the join table has IDs for two separate users, User A and User B. But there are also multiple rows for each week. So it looks like this:

*Schedule Table:*

```
-----------------------------------
| week_id |  userA_id  | userB_id |
-----------------------------------
|    1    |     1      |   2      |   
|    1    |     2      |   3      |
----------------------------------
```

I also have a user table which stores all the information about a user, pretty basic stuff. So, for instance:

*User Table:*

```
-----------------------------------
|    id   |    Name    | Nickname |
-----------------------------------
|    1    |    jason   |   jay    |   
|    2    |    billy   |   bill   |
----------------------------------
```

What I'd like to do is query my schedule table based on the Week ID and then return a series of users for each Week. So for instance, give me all the users from week 1 in a series of objects, something like [ { UserA.name: jason, UserB.name: billy }, { UserA.name : billy, UserB.name: jane } ], etc.

I have a sneaking suspicion that this will include multiple JOIN statements, but I can't seem to get it working. Does anyone know how to structure this MySQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option here is just to join the `Schedule` table twice to the `User` table, one join for each user in the relationship.

```
SELECT u1.Name,
       u2.Name
FROM Schedule s
INNER JOIN User u1
    ON s.userA_id = u1.id
INNER JOIN User u2
    ON s.userB_id = u2.id
WHERE s.week_id = 1
```

Comment: Yea sorry, deleted the previous comment. My error. Thanks, I believe this is working perfect!